# an API to connect to a shared resource on a Novell server

Tags: windows, api, client, novell

Currently we access to the shared files on our Novel server from a client by adding `NWLink IPX/SPX` protocol to the network interface and setting up a connection.

Now we have to do this automatically in a software running on Windows. So I am looking for way to setup appropriate setting to connect to the Novel server (e.g. adding `NWLink IPX/SPX` support to the network interface, mapping a network drive) and access the files and disconnects from the server, all *programatically*.

Another choice would be using a thrid-party library that provides an API to connect to a Novell server, access the files, etc. but I cannot find any library for this. The only thing I have found is [Novell Client](http://www.novell.com/products/openenterpriseserver/features/clients.html) which doesn't provide an API for the other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Both with the Novell Client and with the NWLink IPX/SPX windows client you can shell out to a command line and execute "net use" with the appropriate syntax for what you want.

You can specify a /user and a /password with net use, so that sounds like it would suffice.